# Syntax to route Rails form_for to custom controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, form-for

Have tried forums, documentation and blog suggestions. They converge on syntax that for me does not properly save AND route through desired controller.

Big picture, I have two software applications that share functionality. To implement shared functionality, I had Rails generate Shared::Widgets. This MVC works just fine. No problem viewing, updating, creating, or deleting using standard shared/widgets & etc routing.

Then, for the product-specific functionality, I created two controllers: Product1::Widgets and Product2::Widgets. Both inherit from Shared::Widgets controller. Both are empty except for product-specific layouts.

This scheme almost works. When I route to product1/widgets, it sets layout to product1 and invokes index method of shared/widgets. The result is display of shared/widgets/index.html.erb with product1 layout. Similarly, when I route to product2/widgets, this sets product2 layout and invokes index method of shared/widgets. The result is display of shared/widgets/index.html.erb with product2 layout. Perfect.

But now we get to the form_for. Because it implements the rails magic, it really really wants to route directly to Shared::Widgets controller. But that's not what I want. I want it to route to the appropriate product controller so as to set layout. The rails generated form_for was something like this:

```
form_for(@shared_widget, :html => { :class => "form"}) do |f|
```

I tried:

```
form_for([:product1, @widget], :html => { :class => "form"}) do |f|
```

but that duplicates namespace (product1_widget_shared_widget_path).

I tried the following three formats, all of which seem to route correctly, and save the record, but the record is empty (columns are blank):

```
form_for(@widget, url => "product1/widget", :html => { :class => "form"}) do |f| 

form_for(@widget, url => url_for(:controller => "widget"), :html => { :class => "form"}) do |f| 

form_for(@widget, url => url_for(:controller => "widget", :action => "create"), :html => { :class => "form"}) do |f|
```

Any help? If the above code has spelling errors, it is due to transcription. The actual code I used passed the interpreter. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
form_for(url: { controller: "posts", action: "create" }, html => { :class => "form" }, method: "post") do |f|
```

Comment: should be :html i think